# "unable to resolve class" error after upgrading gradle 3 to gradle 4

Tags: gradle, grails

- Grails version: 3.2.9
- Gradle initial version: 3.4.1 (everything works fine with this version)
- Gradle upgraded version:4.10.3
- Plugin: org.grails.grails-gsp

When I run `gradlew war` after upgrading gradle version to `4.10.3` I start to get the following error during execution of `compileGroovyPages` task:

> dashboard_gsp.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class com.abnd.CarStatusEnum
>
> @ line 2, column 1.
>
> import  com.abnd.CarStatusEnum
>
> ^

Location of class `com.abnd.CarStatusEnum` is `src/main/groovy/com/abnd/CarStatusEnum` in the same project where the build is being run and `gradlew war` task completes successfully with gradle version 3.4.1. However when I upgrade gradle version to 4.10.3 then I start to get this error. Same happens with gradle version 4.1.

1) Any clue what can be the problem ?

2) Is that a good idea to use gradle version 4.x.x or 5.x.x with grails version 3.x.x as with gradle 5.x.x I start to get even more issues as some grails plugins(like grails-gsp v3.3.2 which is latest stable version) use some features that have been deprecated in gradle 4.x.x and removed from gradle 5.x.x (see the error bellow)?

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.grails.grails-gsp']
>
> Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.

Comment: You have some things out of sync in the build.  Without seeing the source it may be difficult to say exactly what that is.  I recommend using Gradle 5.1.1 with Grails 4.0.0.RC1.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I can't upgrade grails at the moment, just need to upgrade gradle in order to be able to use a mature version of build cache. Unfortunately I can't post my build scripts here for obvious reasons, but would like to know how to proceed, as error message doesn't help much. Is that possible that `org.grails.grails-gsp` plugin is not compatible with gradle 4 ?

Comment: I would start by creating a new project with whatever version of Grails you are using and compare that build script to your upgraded one and see if anything jumps out as looking relevant.

Comment: 100 apologies. I misread the title.  I thought you were upgrading from Grails 3 to Grails 4.  I see now that you are upgrading from Gradle 3 to Gradle 4.  I am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Any clue what can be the problem ?

Yes.  The error message is a clue that the GSP compiler can't find the enum class.  This is because our plugin isn't compatible with Gradle 4.10.3.

> 2) Is that a good idea to use gradle version 4.x.x or 5.x.x with
>   grails version 3.x.x

No.  Those Gradle versions are not supported with the version of Grails you are using.

I hope that helps.

Comment: btw... You could get around that particular error by not having import statements (or code that relies on import statements) in your GSP to begin with, that is never a great idea, but that is just going to move you on to other issues related to the version incompatibilities.

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there an official compatibility chart for grails vs gradle versions ?